# Microsoft learn by loading every modules i got this error : "Unauthorized Sandbox use detected. Your sandbox has been terminated."

Tags: azure

since 3 days, my `"Microsoft Learn"` account can not load azure sandbox anymore, I got this error message:

> Unauthorized Sandbox use detected. Your sandbox has been terminated.

Actually, I did nothing, but visit a module called `"Secure your Azure resources with role-based access control (RBAC)"` in `MSLEARN.` in this module, by loading sandbox, it shows a different message, unlike other modules, i.e. "Loading Azure Portal...". afterwards, I find out my account does not work anymore.

In order to check this problem only for my account is, I have created another account, it works well.

I think my account has some problem, regarding my using. i did not find an answer in FAQ from Microsoft Learn

Comment: Maybe the permission of your account has expired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS is currently resolving "abuse" of MS Learn resources, by crashing everything. You'll see other errors like:

- no resources available...
- policy denied...
- ...

New: I created another MS account and it works well. So it seems that MS has introduced some kind of quota per user usage of their MS learn sandboxes... Very stupid indeed, I'd like to pass tutorials at least with my Azure subscription, and now I can't mark tutorials complete and track the learning progress...

Comment: I have the same issue since yesterday :(